# Make projectile go to destination in game from scratch

Tags: android, math, vector, projectile

I realize this question has been answered in different ways, and my current solution is based on a previous answer, but it doesn't quite work for me and I can't figure out why.

```
            float targetX = bullet.getTarget().x;
            float targetY = bullet.getTarget().y;
            float bulletX = bullet.getLocation().x;
            float bulletY = bullet.getLocation().y;

            // Version of setX(getX() + (speed * Math.cos(direction)));
            float deltaX = targetX - bulletX;
            float deltaY = targetY - bulletY;
            float direction = (float) Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
            float x = bulletX + BULLET_SPEED * (float) Math.cos(direction);
            float y = bulletY + BULLET_SPEED * (float) Math.sin(direction);
            bullet.setLocation(x, y);
```

Here is the results in action:

[Animated Gif Of The Bullet Going The (Almost Right) Direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8xJ0.gif)

Is there a problem with my math?

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being the border of the canvas offsetting the destination point, so I compensated for it and got something close to accurate behavior.